# Show Folium.Map object in Tkinter window

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, geopandas, folium

I have a shapefile that I read using geopandas and then use the explore function to show a dynamic map containing the shape I have with data that pop ups and a colorbar.
My problem is I cannot get it to show up in the Tkinter window.

Now when I write this code:

```
my_shape = gpd.read_file("my_file_location")
m = my_shape.explore(column="IDspeed", tooltip="IDspeed", tiles=False, style_kwds=dict(weight=1, opacity=1, fillOpacity=1), cmap="Reds")

folium.TileLayer('openstreetmap', control=True, opacity=0.25,name="openstreetmap").add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

it shows the map and the shape perfectly, but I cannot make the same thing to show in a Tkinter window, I have tried saving the map object as html, but still cannot do it, is there an straightforward way to display this in the Tkinter window itself?

Thanks for the help.